# Как реализовать построчный вывод строк в DataMemo в RaveReports?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, ravereport

Пробовал перенести строку в самом редакторе компонента DataMemo (см рис.), но не прошло.

Необходимо реализовать что-то подобное:

> 1. петров
> 2. иванов
> 3. арбуз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `string1 + sLineBreak + string2` или `string1 + #13#10 + string2`

Comment: А разве DataText не размещается в специальном DataBand, после чего он автоматически выведет данные если подключен источник. см. например [тут](http://www.snkey.net/books/delphi/ch4-6.html)

Comment: @Kromster - такие штуки дают (invalid) или это надо ещё на уровне Delphi кода прописать?

Comment: @androschuk, если честно, то Rave Reports первый раз в глаза вижу. Ни чего в нём не умею. Даже подключиться к БД (MySQL) не смог. Раньше ведь привычный и удобный QuickReport был. Его исключили из Delphi, с тех времён я и не программировал.

Comment: @I_CaR Если не критично - лучше перейти на FastReport, там все намного понятнее.